# Аутентификация без регистрации

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот, я делаю сайт и там будет опрос. И мне надо, чтобы один пользователь мог один раз нажать только, но без регистрации. Как мне это осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кукисы небезопасны! Даже недалекому юзеру не составит особого труда их удалить и проголосовать несколько раз. В этих целях безопасности браузера недостаточно. Чтобы создать безопасный и надежный код, необходим PHP. Там уже сверять можно и по IP.

Comment: Ага, по динамическому IP. «Кукисы небезопасны»? Покажите мне хоть одного, кому они навредили.
Вообще, если уж делать действительно задаваться целью идентификации, каждый браузер имеет свой уникальный ID, который можно использовать в качестве идентификатора пользователя.

Comment: @Realetive__,  Если вы так говорите, то ничего не смыслите в информационной безопасности...."в качестве идентификатора пользователя", ну да, изменил идентификатор, и все, ты уже имеешь права другого пользователя!

Answer (score 3):

Можно дополнительно идентифицировать пользователя по сумме всей отправляемой им информации. Каждый бит (User-Agent, предпочтения языка, установленные плагины) дает свой вклад. Посмотрите, как это делает [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Еще вариант, можно «сувать» уникальные идентификаторы в заголовок ETag, кэш браузера и LSO флэш-плеера (при наличии) и еще кучу не совсем типичных мест. Вот здесь подробнее: http://samy.pl/evercookie/, http://habrahabr.ru/tag/evercookie/.

Еще, как вариант, в дополнение к cookies, попросите у пользователя OpenID или аккаунт ВКонтакте/Facebook/Twitter. Готовых решений для OpenID и OAuth — на любой вкус, большинство пользователей проголосует все так же, в один-два клика. Если аудитория мейнстримная, то много посетителей не отсеется. И никакой регистрации, да.

Плюс, как уже сказали, записывайте IP-адреса и ведите аудит-статистику. Если с какого-то адреса слишком аномально голосуют (цифры выбиваются из общего распределения) — это повод разобраться. Руками, увы — машины тут могут только натолкнуть на следы, но разбираться в них у них «ума» не хватит.

Чем выше безопасность/защищенность, тем ниже удобство и простота реализации — и наоборот. Балансируйте между этими факторами на свой вкус.

Answer (score 1):

В куки + в базу пиши ip, которые уже голосовали.

Answer (score -3):

Наверное, cookies. Это из простого и очевидного.

Comment: ну куки легко изменить, может как-то лучше по ip